# Multithreading and concurrency - how to make rest application using singleton beans well designed?

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, web, concurrency

I have `@RestController("tables")` with the following dependency:

```
private Map<String, Table> tables;
```

Field `tables` was declared in *SpringConfig* as *singleton* *bean* and contains information about all tables.
Before updating some table, you should validate if it exists, and only in this case to access database.
After creating you should add table in tables, etc.

Controller can execute *CRUD* operations with tables.

***How should I provide correct working with sharing of resources?***
As I know, I can use ConcurrentHashMap instead ordinary HashMap. In this case It will good work with adding and putting, but when it's needed to update value(its fields) I will have problems.

And if I have as dependency for example some `private` `Table table` - singleton bean, should I use `synchronized` block or something else?

If you could, give me some examples to understand how It works.
The main idea is to comprehend how to prevent emergence of invalid data when different threads have an access to the same resource.

Comment: You can define the entries as immutable data and just replace the whole entry in the `ConcurrentHashMap` on update. Otherwise you need to ensure that each of the entries are themselves threadsafe

Comment: How are the fields stored in the map? Is it a JSON, comma separated list or an `ArrayList`? If it's not a `List` data structure, can't you use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`? From the nature of the problem, it doesn't look like a very busy process. If that is the case, can't you just use any kind of simple to code lock like `synchronized`? If not, please clarify the problem with these details and your understanding of why these cannot be done?

Comment: @flakes and if I have a situation when my entries can't be immutable, how can i update It in map?

Comment: @SaptarshiBasu map contains key-String and value-bean(pojo) created from json

Comment: @SaptarshiBasu I can use any possibilities including synchronized but I don't have practice with multithreading and seek for advice to be sure that my undestanding how to solve this problem is correct. How to work with map, how to update map value(and save the previous value chanding only some fields), and how to work with java beans. With beans i think i can just use synchronized inside controller methods when we have an access to this bean, is it correct?